# Struggling to import maven dependency from SourceForge

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-dependency-plugin

Trying to use a Project called **simmetrics**: http://sourceforge.net/projects/simmetrics/

Trying to add the project as a **maven dependancy** into the **POM** file as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.simmetrics</groupId>
    <artifactId>simmetrics</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I've also added the **repository** as follows:

```
<repository> <id>simmetrics.website</id>
     <name>Simmetrics Website</name>
     <url>http://sourceforge.net/projects/simmetrics/</url>
</repository>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction, this seems rather silly.

Thanks for your time.

EDIT

Found it somewhere else, however I can't seem to access this either:
     https://dev-iesl.cs.umass.edu/nexus/content/groups/public/

```
 <repository>
      <id>IESL Releases</id>
      <name>IESL Repo</name>
      <url>https://dev-iesl.cs.umass.edu/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
 </repository>


 <dependency>
    <groupId>uk.ac.shef.wit.simmetrics</groupId>
    <artifactId>simmetrics</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

In case some one is wondering yes I'm using various other maven dependencies, never experienced this before though.

Comment: The Repository you have configured is not a Maven repository. Just a Download page. Does not work. They should deliver their jars into Maven Central as requested on their tracking tool: http://sourceforge.net/p/simmetrics/feature-requests/2/ If they don't you need to download it manuall compile it and install it your own repository manager.

Comment: Yes I saw that, but they did at one point, however the page doesn't exist any more. You could do it via there own Shef Uni repository.

I did however find this: `https://dev-iesl.cs.umass.edu/nexus/content/groups/public/` which has it, i.e. goto uk -> ac -> shef -> wit -> simmetrics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost every company/user that wants to post its source code as a maven project and allow others to depend on it do it by the following options:

1. Publish it in the maven Central Repository (see [maven central repository](http://search.maven.org/))
2. Create its own repository, publish it, and add the dependency of the selected Jar to it

All the other options are simple, download the Jar and use it.

If this is your only option (download the Jar and use it), consider creating your own repository and add this Jar to it.

Comment: Thanks, fair enough :) I just wanted to avoid doing that, since I found it in a different repository, i.e. see edit in my original post

Answer (score 1):

SimMetrics is available on Maven central. You can include it by adding this dependency to your pom.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.mpkorstanje</groupId>
    <artifactId>simmetrics-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Full disclaimer: I seem to be the current maintainer.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to configure your pom.xml to use repositories from vendors or code authors, such as the simmetrics. Their official repository is hosted by John Hopkins University, where the code was developed. So, adding this to your pom.xml should do the trick:  (**Note, as of the time of this writing, the repository is not responding, but I've been using it for awhile now without any problems**)

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>msel.releases</id>
        <name>Johns Hopkins Sheridan Libraries Maven 2 Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.mse.jhu.edu/m2repository</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```